# Deeply nested data structures in redis

Tags: redis

For example i have array of objects

```
  messages = [
    {
      name: user1,
      messages: [
        {
          user2: [message1, message2]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: user2,
      messages: [
        {
          user1: [message1, message2]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

What is the best way to store it in redis cache? I would want to update it each time message is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to store this information in redis.

- Make jsonString of object and store simple key/Value pair.

  - Advantage: good practive, json parsing seems fast in this case.
- Use HashMap to store the jsonObject in redis.

  - Advantage : No need to parse JSON object.
  - Disadvantage : Objects withing objects cannot be stored.

For use case go for the option 1.

Comment: that's how i did